# How does flyway decide order of execution for sql scripts

Tags: flyway

How does flyway decide order of execution for sql scripts.

I have attached a screenshot of scripts I have in my project in various directories; but it executed it in different order than I expected. Also, the execution order varies if I ran the scripts in incremental manner or all at the same time.

Here's the order I expected them to execute in.

[image]

Here's the order they got executed in.

[image]

I am using flyway-core 4.0.3 with sprint boot. I have set flyway.out-of-order=true.

Comment: What order is it executed in? Can you also provide your xml configuration please.

Comment: I updated my question to provide the actual order of execution.

Comment: It seems the actual version order is being followed which means your out-of-order = true configuration is not being used. Are you sure your XML configuration is correct?

Comment: I dont have any XML configuration since I am on spring boot. All I do is add flyway-core dependency and properties for flyway credentials and out of order=true. Also, for actual order, does 1.2.002 come ahead of 1.003? If I go pure mathematical - 1.003 < 1.2.002. That's why I was trying to understand how is the order decided.

Comment: It seems that flyway ignores leading zeroes unless only zero is present. 1.1.1 is same as 1.1.001. 1.0.1 remains 1.0.1 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway ignores leading zeroes between dots and that's why the order was different than what I expected. Once I removed leading zeroes; the scripts were executed in order I expected.